# OCaml function definition

Tags: function, ocaml, function-definition

Can somebody tell me the difference between these two definitions ?

```
let f x y = x + y;;
```

which yields `val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>`

and  this definition

```
let f = fun x y -> x + y;;
```

which also yields `val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>` ?

Comment: There is no difference. That's the point. The first is just short-hand syntax for the second, which is also a short-hand for `fun x -> fun y -> x + y`.

Answer (score 1):

All functions in OCaml take a single argument, and return a single value.

Here's a function that demonstrates this.

```
fun x -> x + 1
```

We can apply this function to a value.

```
(fun x -> x + 1) 2
```

But this is inconvenient, so we bind a name to this function.

```
let inc = fun x -> x + 1
```

Functions *are* values in OCaml, so a function can return a function.

```
let add = fun x -> fun y -> x + y
```

We can now apply this:

```
(add 1) 1
```

Or because of how this is processed:

```
add 1 1
```

All of this is very inconvenient in practice, there is shorthand syntax so we can just write:

```
let add x y = x + y
```

But consider again:

```
let add = fun x -> fun y -> x + y
```

This if a function that takes an argument and spits out a function that takes an argument. What if we stop at providing that first argument? Well, then we get a function back that takes the second argument and produces a sum.

```
let inc = add 1
```

In this case, we've *partially applied* the `add` function. This lets us take bits of code like:

```
let some_list = [2; 3; 4] in
List.map (fun x -> add 1 x) some_list
```

And express it as:

```
let some_list = [2; 3; 4] in
List.map (add 1) some_list
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

```
let f x y = x + y
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
let f = fun x y -> x + y
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
let f = function x -> function y -> x + y
```

It's all the same and you can do for example

```
let incr = f 1
```

with any of them.